# External JavaScript file not changing files using it

Tags: javascript

So I have a JavaScript file sidebar.js that contains the text to be displayed in my drop down menu I ised this so I could easily change the links if I add another page to my website Instead of changing the content of the drop down for 15+ pages. My problem is when I try to add another link to the file nothing happens to the pages using it! The file was saved and changed but I doesn't change the websites using it!

If you need any more information pertaining to this question I would be welcome to give it to you!

Comment: Sorry what's a cache?

Comment: The browser cache, where it stores files so every time you go to the page it does not need to refetch them so your surfing is fast. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en

Comment: Try Ctrl + F5 to refresh your browser and cache when refreshing the page in the browser.

Comment: Thanks! Can I do that on mobile too? Cuz I looked at my website on my phone too.